# Configuring Hibernate with HikariCP

Tags: java, hibernate, database-connection, c3p0, hikaricp

Because of problems with c3p0 connection pool, I want to see the alternatives and decide which one might be more usable in my case. HikariCP looks very promising, but there is no documentation how to use it with Hibernate.

So far I am using c3p0 as follows:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${database.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${database.structure}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">${database.connection}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">${database.username}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">${database.password}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">${database.driver}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.shutdown">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.writedelay">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${database.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.metamodel.generation">disabled</prop>
            <!-- Use the C3P0 connection pool provider -->
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">30</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">600</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
```

Can someone point me how to configure HikariCP in such way?

Comment: so, wrt c3p0, you have a bad misconfoguration in the bit above. global max_statements of 50 is way too small for the size of your pool; you're forcing the statement cache to churn through statements. set max_statements to 0 to turn statement caching off if you want behavior comparable to HikariCP. you don't specify what problems you are currently having with c3p0, but you might also consider a more reliable testing regime.

Comment: I've experimented with the values above, but in all cases I keep getting randomly (roughly once a day) "Apparent deadlocks". On the other hand, the `max_statement` value I've tried only to increase, but never to disable. I can certainly try that. However, this question is about configuring Hikari with Hibernate.

Comment: oh, i know. and Hikari looks very interesting, very much worth trying out. if you want help c3p0 debugging, let me know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP), as of version 1.2.6, now supports Hibernate 4.x explicitly with a *ConnectionProvider*.  See the new [wiki documentation](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Hibernate4) for details.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: This is no longer the suggested way to use HikariCP in Hibernate - please see my answer which includes details.

Comment: great library my dude

Answer (score 36):

You can use the `org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider` which is shipped by `hibernate-hikaricp` package.

You can install it as Maven dependency (please don't forget to update the version number):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-hikaricp</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

And configure it in the `hibernate.properties` file, like this:

```
hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider
```

Please note: As of Hibernate 4.3.6 you should **no longer** use `com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider` (see: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Hibernate4)

Comment: Author of HikariCP here.  I can confirm that this is now the correct answer.

Comment: @uwolfer I think you've meant: As of Hibernate 4.3.6 don't use com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider any more ;)

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE: See uwolfer's answer below, it is now the official way to use HikariCP with Hibernate.

I'm one of the authors of HikariCP.  I don't claim to be a Spring guy, and I weened off of Hibernate a few years back, but this link might be helpful:

http://www.luckyryan.com/2013/02/20/spring-mvc-with-basic-persistence-spring-data-jpa-hibernate/

In the XML configuration section on that page, where their example uses *BoneCP* as the *mainDataSource*, simply try replacing that section with configuration for *HikariCP* instead.

In your example above, you appear to be configuring Hibernate through Spring and defining the `DataSource` inside of the Hibernate config, which is fine.  But an alternative (presented on that page) is to configure the `DataSource` separately through Spring and then directing Hibernate to use it.

Regarding statement caching, *HikariCP* does not do it because we believe that is best left to the vendors' JDBC driver/DataSource.  Almost every major DB vendors' JDBC `DataSource` provides statement caching, and it can be configured *through* HikariCP by specifying `DataSource` properties.  Refer to the [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) github page for how to set properties on the underlying (vendor) `DataSource`.

Comment: Actually, I've already seen this document, but I don't like their solution as it is quite complex in comparison to the c3p0 solution above. I don't like the fact, that they actually need to write some code instead of just configuring it via XML. Is that even possible with HikariCP? If so, are you planning to write some tutorials for using it? I think you would get much more people using it if it was more straightforward.

Comment: As far as I understood that page, they present two ways of accomplishing the same task: *xml* and *programatically*.  The programatic approach is entirely optional, there should be no Java code required.  I find the separation of the ``DataSource`` and ``Hibernate`` config compelling.  Not to mince words, I also find the Hibernate ``ConnectionProvider`` semantic an abomination and were I working at JBoss the engineer would be fired.  Basically it introduces a new interface whose only contribution is ``supportsAggressiveRelease`` which could easily be expressed as a config property.

Comment: Okay, I will go through it once more. However, it would be great to have pure Hikari tutorials.

Comment: I don't disagree Re: tutorials, I started one for this very topic over on the github wiki.  Though at this point it is largely borrowed from the link above, I hope to improve it over time.

Comment: i tried the switch from BoneCP to HikariCP (just like @brettw said0 but i'm getting `[com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>()` any ideas?

Comment: See [this page](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Hibernate4) for how to use HikariCP with Hibernate.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem as @oak when I try to implement [this](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Spring-Hibernate)

Comment: Can you come over to the [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/hikari-cp) and post your Spring configuration?  We have several users using Spring/Hibernate successfully, it sounds like a simple configuration issue.

Comment: Thanks for information. I configured my spring project with a configured `HikariDataSource` and my `EntityManagerFactoryBean` is using this data source. And I use hibernate just as JPA provider (using Spring's `HibernateJpaVendorAdapter`). So, basically all connections are used from hikari data source. It is working and I can see the connection pool. At this point, do I need do something else like telling Hibernate explicitly to use Hikari?

Comment: Your EntityManager *is* Hibernate, correct?  It sounds like it is working, so what is the question?  If it is not working, I suggest posting a full question here.  You will probably get more answers.